# Determine if 2 lists have the same elements, regardless of order?

Tags: python, list, equality, python-2.x

Sorry for the simple question, but I'm having a hard time finding the answer.

When I compare 2 lists, I want to know if they are "equal" in that they have the same contents, but in different order.

Ex:

```
x = ['a', 'b']
y = ['b', 'a']
```

I want `x == y` to evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

You can simply check whether the multisets with the elements of x and y are equal:

```
import collections
collections.Counter(x) == collections.Counter(y)
```

This requires the elements to be hashable; runtime will be in `O(n)`, where `n` is the size of the lists.

If the elements are also unique, you can also convert to sets (same asymptotic runtime, may be a little bit faster in practice):

```
set(x) == set(y)
```

If the elements are not hashable, but sortable, another alternative (runtime in `O(n log n)`) is

```
sorted(x) == sorted(y)
```

If the elements are neither hashable nor sortable you can use the following helper function. Note that it will be quite slow (`O(n²)`) and should generally **not** be used outside of the esoteric case of unhashable and unsortable elements.

```
def equal_ignore_order(a, b):
    """ Use only when elements are neither hashable nor sortable! """
    unmatched = list(b)
    for element in a:
        try:
            unmatched.remove(element)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return not unmatched
```

Comment: `equal_ignore_order` is a nice approach. I think, it could be improved by checking equalitiy of the lengths of `a` and `b` first. This will speeding things up a little (or a lot, depending on the input).

Comment: set(x) == set(y) does not work just by itself. It would work for the specific example of this question, but it could be buggy for other cases, such as x = ['a', 'b', 'a'], y = ['b', 'a']. For this case, set(x) == set(y) would return True, but someone could argue it to be False. We would have to add len(x) == len(y) for it to fully work. However, we don´t have this issue with sorted(x) == sorted(y)

Comment: @ArmanMojaver the answer explicitly mentions that the elements must be unique.
Also, no, comparing lengths will not matter if there are duplicates. Consider the following scenario:
x = ['a', 'a', 'b'], y = ['a', 'b', 'b']
Both set(x) == set(y) and len(x) == len(y) are True, yet we can clearly see that x != y.

Answer (score 44):

> **Determine if 2 lists have the same elements, regardless of order?**

Inferring from your example:

```
x = ['a', 'b']
y = ['b', 'a']
```

that the elements of the lists won't be repeated (they are unique) as well as hashable (which strings and other certain immutable python objects are), **the most direct and computationally efficient answer** uses Python's builtin sets, (which are semantically like mathematical sets you may have learned about in school).

```
set(x) == set(y) # prefer this if elements are hashable
```

In the case that the elements are hashable, but non-unique, the `collections.Counter` also works semantically as a multiset, but *it is far slower*:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(x) == Counter(y)
```

Prefer to use `sorted`:

```
sorted(x) == sorted(y)
```

if the elements are orderable. This would account for non-unique or non-hashable circumstances, but this could be much slower than using sets.

## Empirical Experiment

An empirical experiment concludes that one should prefer `set`, then `sorted`. Only opt for `Counter` if you need other things like counts or further usage as a multiset.

First setup:

```
import timeit
import random
from collections import Counter

data = [str(random.randint(0, 100000)) for i in xrange(100)]
data2 = data[:]     # copy the list into a new one

def sets_equal(): 
    return set(data) == set(data2)

def counters_equal(): 
    return Counter(data) == Counter(data2)

def sorted_lists_equal(): 
    return sorted(data) == sorted(data2)
```

And testing:

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat(sets_equal))
13.976069927215576
>>> min(timeit.repeat(counters_equal))
73.17287588119507
>>> min(timeit.repeat(sorted_lists_equal))
36.177085876464844
```

So we see that comparing sets is the fastest solution, and comparing sorted lists is second fastest.

Comment: If you have the lists `[1, 1, 8]` and `[1, 8, 8]`, then using sets isn't applicable because the elements are actually different!

Comment: @IanRehwinkel is that not apparent in my answer?

Comment: I must have overread that part. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, though possibly cumbersome for large lists.

```
>>> A = [0, 1]
>>> B = [1, 0]
>>> C = [0, 2]
>>> not sum([not i in A for i in B])
True
>>> not sum([not i in A for i in C])
False
>>>
```

However, if each list *must* contain all the elements of other then the above code is problematic.

```
>>> A = [0, 1, 2]
>>> not sum([not i in A for i in B])
True
```

The problem arises when `len(A) != len(B)` and, in this example, `len(A) > len(B)`. To avoid this, you can add one more statement.

```
>>> not sum([not i in A for i in B]) if len(A) == len(B) else False
False
```

One more thing, I benchmarked my solution with timeit.repeat, under the same conditions used by Aaron Hall in his post. As suspected, the results are disappointing. My method is the last one. `set(x) == set(y)` it is.

```
>>> def foocomprehend(): return not sum([not i in data for i in data2])
>>> min(timeit.repeat('fooset()', 'from __main__ import fooset, foocount, foocomprehend'))
25.2893661496
>>> min(timeit.repeat('foosort()', 'from __main__ import fooset, foocount, foocomprehend'))
94.3974742993
>>> min(timeit.repeat('foocomprehend()', 'from __main__ import fooset, foocount, foocomprehend'))
187.224562545
```

Comment: Should not be a surprise as your method is O(N^2), that is much much bigger than O(N) or O(N * log N).
For every element of B (N elements) it is checking all the elements of A (N elements). The number of checks is then N * N.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments above, the general case is a pain. It is fairly easy if all items are hashable or all items are sortable. However I have recently had to try solve the general case. Here is my solution. I realised after posting that this is a duplicate to a solution above that I missed on the first pass. Anyway, if you use slices rather than list.remove() you can compare immutable sequences.

```
def sequences_contain_same_items(a, b):
    for item in a:
        try:
            i = b.index(item)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        b = b[:i] + b[i+1:]
    return not b
```