# My anagram code doesn't account for multiple letters

Tags: python, anagram

So my code gets two words, and checks if one is the anagram of another one.

However doesn't work if multiple letters are exchanged, although I tried to account for that.

```
storedword = input("Enter your primary word \t")
global word 
word = list(storedword)


word3 = input("Enter anagram word \t")
word3lowercase = word3.lower()
anaw = list(word3lowercase)


counter = int(0)
letterchecker = int(0)
listlength = len(word)
newcounter = int(0)
if len(anaw) != len(word):
    print ("not anagram")

if len(anaw) == len(word):
    while counter < listlength and newcounter < listlength:
        tempcount = 0
        if anaw[counter] == word[newcounter]:
            temp = word[newcounter]
            word[newcounter] = word[tempcount]
            word[tempcount]=temp
            letterchecker +=1
            counter +=1
            tempcount +=1
            newcounter = int(0)

        else:
            newcounter +=1

if counter == len(word):
    print ("anagram")
else:
    print ("not anagram")
```

I think it's gone somewhere wrong after the `if len(anaw)` section, for example if the primary word is "hannah", and the secondary word is "hannnn", it thinks it's an anagram.

Comment: Can you explain the logic you tried to implement here? Also... `int(0)`???

Comment: Also you can simply go `sorted(first_word) == sorted(second_word)` and save yourself all this trouble

Comment: meant anagram, i edited it

Comment: ah, not allowed to use sorted fuction, had to be loops and stuff

Comment: @IHaque If an answer has solved your question please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newcounter = int(0)
```

This is the line that causes the trouble (in the while loop).
Because of it you start checking the word from the beginning again.
I think you want it to be `newcounter=letterchecker`.
Since already used characters are put to the front of `word` they are ignored if you start with letterchecker

Tell me if it works

Edit:Checked with example given, seems to work.

Comment: sure `int(0)` causes me trouble too

Comment: Nah, the same problem occurs

Comment: Did you change the first one, or the one in the while loop?
I meant the one in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

There is much simpler logic that can be implemented here, even without using `sorted` and such. Let's assume you have a function `anagram`:

```
def anagram(word1, word2):
    if len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False

    def char_count(word):
        char_count = {}
        for c in word:
            char_count[c] = char_count.get(c, 0) + 1
        return char_count

    cr1 = char_count(word1)
    cr2 = char_count(word2)
    return cr1 == cr2
```

You can test this with:

```
>>> print(anagram("anagram", "aanragm"))
True
>>> print(anagram("anagram", "aangtfragm"))
False
```

And for future readers, a super simple pythonic solution might be using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(word1) == Counter(word2)
```

Or using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> sorted(word1) == sorted(word2)
```

Comment: You can use a `set` to avoid re-checking similar characters. Also, I'd add the `Counter(word) == Counter(otherword)` solution for the sake of future readers.

Comment: @ReutSharabani I figured he might not be able to import/use `Counter`. Regarding the `set` I might edit later (not next to a computer so I don't want to make any changes without testing them). You are welcome to edit my answer tho ;)

Comment: I know he isn't, but the answer doesn't have to be too specific. If a future reader runs into this he may want the nicer solution. That's why I wrote "for the sake of *future* readers" :-)

Comment: if it is for future readers, you should precise `from collections import Counter`

Comment: Haha okay sure I'll edit this a lil later then for all the millions of future readers who will flock to this answer like wild geese ;p

Comment: For the other answers that aren't restricted. [Determine if 2 lists have the same elements, regardless of order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8866652/5012922)

Answer (score 0):

Without using `sort` you could use the following approach. It removes a letter from an array of a characters of the second word. The words are only anagrams if there are no letters left (and the words are the same length to start with and have a length larger than zero):

```
word1="hannah"
word2="nahpan"

chars1= list(word1)
chars2= list(word2)

if len(chars1)==len(chars2) and len(chars1)>0:
    for char in chars1:
        if char not in chars2:
           break
        chars2.remove(char)                   


if len(chars2)==0:
    print "Both words are anagrams"
else:
    print "Words are not anagrams"
```

Comment: what does that char for char mean?

Comment: It's just all the chars in each word, it will make `chars1` to be `['h', 'a', 'n', 'n', 'a', 'h']`

Comment: It converts the words in an array of characters. I have changed the code to use `list`, looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

[EDIT THIS IS JUST FOR PALINDROMES I CANT READ]

Here is something a bit more simple:

```
storedword = input("Enter your primary word \t")
word3 = input("Enter anagram word \t")
if storedword == word3[::-1]:
    print "Is Anagram"
else:
    print "Is not anagram"
```

Comment: Anagrams are not palindromes.

Comment: but palindromes are anagrams :)

Comment: @user1723662: this is wrong, `word3[::-1]` simply reverts `words3`

Comment: Sorry when I saw anagram I though palindrome!

Comment: @user1723662 you do know that you can **delete** your answer, right?