# I can't understand why it won't return True always, since the ''return True'' statement is outside the loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Assuming played_chicket and winning_chicket are 2 random lists wiht 4 elements each, what does this loop returns? I can't understand the logic behind it. Won't it return True always because the ''return True'' statement is outside the loop? I know it will return false if any of the elements are different but i can't see why. Can someone please, explain it to me?

```
def check_ticket(played_ticket, winning_ticket):
    # Check all elements in the played ticket. If any are not in the 
    #   winning ticket, return False.
    for element in played_ticket:
        if element not in winning_ticket:
            return False
     
    # We must have a winning ticket!
    return True
```

Comment: There is no `return True` in your code

Comment: Hey Adriano, could you show us the entire code and provide an input example for `played_ticket, winning_ticket` please?

Comment: hey guys, the return True statement was missing, here is the right version of the code

Comment: Right now (which is to say, as of [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71595707/2) of the question), that `return True` is _not in the function at all_ -- it would need to be indented more to be part of the function

Comment: Anyhow, remember that whenever a `return` statement is reached, _the entire function ends_. It's not "last return wins", it's _first_ return wins, because after a `return` is reached, nothing else in that instance of the function has any chance to run. So when a `return False` is reached, the function is done; it can't exit the loop and then reach `return True`.

Comment: You are basically just reimplementing `all`: `return all(x in played_ticket for x in return_ticket)`. If you can make `winning_ticket` a set, then `return set(winning_ticket).issuperset(played_ticket)`.

Comment: @chepner you can only make it a `set` only if all the elements are unique

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan um, what? You can make a set out of any iterable of hashable objects, and you can certainly use them here

Comment: But wouldn't it be a logical error if you compare `[1,2,2]` to `[1,2]` which are both different tickets? as the set of both is the same. I was just adding to chepner's comment as he said "**If** you can make `winning_ticket` a set", and we don't know the conditions of those tickets.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the first element in `played_ticket` is not in `winning_ticket`

Consider `played_ticket = [0,1,2]` and `winning_ticket = [1,2]`

Your first iteration will look like this:

```py
    for element in played_ticket:
        # element = 0
        if element not in winning_ticket:
            # 0 is not in winning_ticket, so it will return false immediately
            return False
```

---

Your function as is will always return `False` or nothing (becomes `None`). You will need to edit the function to have a fallback `return True`:

```py
def check_ticket(played_ticket, winning_ticket):
    # Check all elements in the played ticket. If any are not in the
    #   winning ticket, return False.
    for element in played_ticket:
        if element not in winning_ticket:
            return False
    # Here
    return True
```

So if every element is in the other list, it will return `True`

---

> See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866652/determine-if-2-lists-have-the-same-elements-regardless-of-order) if you would like to simplify your function

Comment: Your simplified version won't work if the lists are in a different order.

Comment: Oh yep you're right, I will fix now

Answer (score 0):

by turning winning ticket into a list you could invert the process checking if the element is True, return False if nothing is True:

```
def check_ticket(played_ticket, winning_ticket):
# Check all elements in the played ticket. If any are not in the 
#   winning ticket, return False.
    if any(element in winning_ticket for element in played_ticket):
        return True
    return False
```