# remove lists with same elements but in different order, from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I want to filter a list of lists for duplicates. I consider two lists to be a duplicate of each other when they contain the same elements but not necessarily in the same order. So for example

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]
```

should become

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]
```

since `['C', 'B', 'A']` is a duplicate of `['A', 'B', 'C']`.
It does not matter which one of the duplicates gets removed, as long as the final list of lists does not contain any duplicates anymore. And all lists need to keep the order of there elements. So using `set()` may not be an option.

I found this related questions:
[Determine if 2 lists have the same elements, regardless of order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866652/determine-if-2-lists-have-the-same-elements-regardless-of-order) ,
[How to efficiently compare two unordered lists (not sets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828867/how-to-efficiently-compare-two-unordered-lists-not-sets)
But they only talk about how to compare two lists, not how too efficiently remove duplicates. I'm using python.

Comment: Can the lists contain duplicate values? E.g. `['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']` ?

Comment: @Andrej Kesely No, the values in one list will always be different from each other.

Answer (score 4):

using dictionary comprehension

```
>>> data = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]
>>> result = {tuple(sorted(i)): i for i in data}.values()
>>> result 
dict_values([['C', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'B', 'A']])
>>> list( result )
[['C', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `frozenset`

```py
>>> x = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]
>>> [list(s) for s in set([frozenset(item) for item in x])]
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Or, with `map`:

```py
>>> [list(s) for s in set(map(frozenset, x))]
[['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: You can just write set(frozenset(item) for item in x)

Comment: Works well if the order of resulting lists doesn't matter

Comment: @funnydman - `set(frozenset(item) for item in x)` outputs `{frozenset({'D', 'B', 'A'}), frozenset({'C', 'B', 'A'})}` - OP wants `[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the order of elements:

```
data = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]

seen = set()
result = []
for obj in data:
    if frozenset(obj) not in seen:
        result.append(obj)
    seen.add(frozenset(obj))
```

**Output:**

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep the order of elements?

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]

print([k for k, _ in groupby(data, key=sorted)])
```

**Output:**

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]
```

Comment: Yes, the order of elements should stay the same. ```[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]``` is a valid output but ```[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D']]``` is not, since ```['D', 'B', 'A']``` changed to ```['A', 'B', 'D']```

Comment: @AkutLuna  see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268678/remove-lists-with-same-elements-but-in-different-order-from-a-list-of-lists/73271182#73271182

Answer (score 0):

In **python** you have to remember that **you can't change existing data** but you can somehow append / update data.

The simplest way is as follows:

```
dict = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'B', 'A'], ['D', 'B', 'A']]

temp = []
for i in dict:
    if sorted(i) in temp:
        pass
    else:
        temp.append(i)
print(temp)
```

*cheers, athrv*

Comment: use `tmp` as dict or set as it will be O(1) to search value inside them, whereas in list it is O(n)