# Converting a graph to another graph by using operations

Tags: graph-theory

guys! I am stuck with a graph problem I saw 3-4 days ago. It is from the Open Russian Olympiad in Informatics 2004, Tver. You are given two graphs. Each graph consists of N nodes and M edges. You need to turn the first graph into the second or state that it is impossible. You can only use the following operation:

1. Choose 4 different nodes, which are connected 2-by-2 (lets call them v1,v2,v3 and v4 - v1 and v2 are connected and v3 and v4 are connected)
2. Remove these 2 edges that connect each pair and connect them by any other way :
   2.1 v1 with v3 ; v2 with v4
   2.2 v1 with v4 ; v2 with v3
   You can use up to 48000 of these operations.
   Here is a link : https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=1054#1

I tried finding some kind of algorithm or some kind of connection of following operations but it didn't work. I also tried creating my own examples and tried to solve them but I couldn't find any pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** there is a 1:1 correspondence between the vertices in the two graphs i.e. vertex labelled V in graph 1 is the 'same' as the vertex labelled V in graph 2.

- LOOP every 4 group of vertices in graph 1

  - If the vertices are not connected

    - CONTINUE
  - IF the vertex connections in the group **cannot** be transformed to the graph 2 vertex connections of the same vertices.

    - CONTINUE
  - TRANSFORM
  - IF 2 graphs are identical

    - SUCCESS
- ENDLOOP
- FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

After each operation, the degree of each node doesn't change (*v1,v2,v3,v4*), all four nodes lose and gain an edge. Therefore only those *G'=(V',E')* graphs can be considered to be transformed from graph *G=(V,E)* into *G'*, where the set of the node degrees of *G* (*{d(v) : v∈V}*, in Python: `[d(v) for v in V]`) is the same set (not looking at ordering, a.k.a. sorting) as the set of node degrees for *G'*. (You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8866661/19626271) how to check if two sets have the same elements.) I'll show that all these graphs can be obtained.

If the set of node degrees are the same, then you can map the nodes of *G* into the nodes of *G'* in a way such that for all *i*, `d(v'_i)==d(v_i)` (you can do this mapping with dictionaries, I thought of re-sorting the list of node degrees in *G'* based on the values of node degrees in *G*, and then re-indexing).
From here, you can create a set of edges in *G* (or any graph made from modifying *G*) that are "not needed" (they are not in *G'*, but are in *G* as of now, until removed), and a set of edges that are "missing" (they are in *G'*, but they are not in our graph as of yet). Call them collectively "unfixed" edges. Edges both in G and G' would be "good" edges.

The "best algorithm" I discovered is this:
Create a new graph *H*, from the same vertices, but the edges in *H* are the set of unfixed edges, the not-needed edges colored with red, and missing edges colored with yellow (in implementation, you don't need to color them, just look at the sets). In any node that has a red edge connected to it, has a yellow edge too, the amount of yellow and red edges from a node are equal. This way, we have "red-yellow-red-yellow-..."  cycles making up *H* (and nothing else). If in this cycle, we can find 4 consecutive nodes *A-B-C-D* (edges between them red-yellow-red or yellow-red-yellow) where they make a *2x2* connection in *G*, then we make a transition here. There are 2 cases this could happen:

- the cycle's part is red-yellow-red, and then there is no edge between A and D in G (could either represent "no edge" or a yellow missing edge in H), this way, after the transition, we either remove 2 red and 2 yellow edges, or remove 2 red and 1 yellow edge, adding a "new" red edge
- the cycle's part is yellow-red-yellow, and there is an edge between A and D in G, this could be either a good edge, or a red edge. Based on this, again, we either remove 2 yellow and 2 red edges, or remove 2 yellow edges and 1 red edge, and add 1 "new" yellow edge.

Either way, each transition reduces the number of wrong edges by 2 or 4, so after finitely many transitions, we will reach 0 wrong edges, thus we get G' from G. Therefore, all we have to do is continuously make corrections this way until the set of wrong edges become empty. (I am not 100% certain on the correctness of my proof of why we can always find a "correcting" *2x2* if there exist some wrong edges, but I can comment it.)

See the example on the picture: the construction of H, and how in the first iteration, we'd have the green 2x2 connection asserted (through a-b-c-d), after which H updated would have a new yellow edge between c and d, and only the edges in the bottom half, and in the next iteration we get G' as H will be empty.
[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYkfR.jpg)

Comment: What is the overal time complexity of the solution you presented? 
P.S. Thank you for the fast answer of my question :)